# How should i add words to android personal dictionay in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new here, and this is my first post here. I want to know how can I add some words to personal dictionary of android I know the method is user.Dictionary . But I don't know how to use please help me for this problem and your answer is appreciated Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot programmatically add words to the user dictionary. Only the user can add these words on his/her device. You can only access these words via the [UserDictionary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html) provider.